# Canonical setup for duplicate content with service areas

Tags: duplicate-content, canonical-url, ppc

I'm relatively new to SEO and would like to make sure I understand canonicals and website layouts correctly. I'm working on a site for "Bob's Pest Control, Plumbing, and Pizza Delivery" that services all of Houston, TX. I have a few ideas about how to move forward, but I would appreciate any advice about maintaining best practices.

1. Create an optimized page for the general Houston area that lists their services. I would then duplicate these pages, only replacing the location of Houston with Baytown, Conroe, Sugar Land, Galveston, etc. so each page is hyper-focused. These pages would have their canonical set to the Houston page. These near-duplicate pages would be indexed and included in the sitemap.
2. Same as #1, but the pages would not be indexed or linked in the sitemap. These pages would be used for PPC as one-way doorway pages with no navigation link pointing back, making it impossible to find the page without the PPC link.
3. Same as #1, but each page would have "unique" content by running it through a GPT so it isn't identical. These would be indexed with a canonical pointing back to the general Houston page. This gives BPCPPD an organic search advantage while still working for a PPC doorway link.
4. Create completely original pages for each location with self-referencing canonicals. They all offer the same services but are handcrafted to be unique. This would extend for some 30 pages, causing a large increase in time, scope of project, business costs, and great stress for the poor copywriter and website developer (me).

Please let me know if I'm missing any options or misunderstanding canonicals (or anything else). Thanks for reading and I look forward to any responses!